# .profdata file not being detected by compiler

Tags: c++, clang, visual-studio-2019, pgo

I'm trying to enable PGO on a ps4 build on clang.

I'm able to generate the .profraw files using -fprofile-instr-generate and -fprofile-coverage-mapping. I've also merged them to the required .profdata format. However after using -fprofile-instr-use=outputfile.profdata, the compiler is not detecting this file and i'm getting the error :

```
54>EXEC : warning : C:\fastbuild-work\.fbuild.tmp\0x00000000\core_1002\zstd_v02.obj
54>EXEC : error : Could not read profile outputfile.profdata: no such file or directory
54>1 error generated.
54>EXEC : Failed to build Object. error : 1 (0x01) Target: 'C:\fastbuild-work\.fbuild.tmp\0x00000000\core_1002\zstd_v02.obj'
```

I've put the outputfile.profdata file in executable directory, compiler directory, working directory, and immediate directory. I just don't know where to put it anymore